# How to poll a single .NET Core healthcheck service application in different frequencies and customize logs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, iis-10, health-check

We are using https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks as base template to write a customized Health Check (.NET 6)

As per our requirement, this Healthcheck application has to poll an external API endpoint every 10 secs between 1AM to 6 PM and every 1 minute between 6 AM to 1 AM.

There is a setting `HealthChecks.UI.Configuration.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds` which helps us set the polling time.

Is there anyway to change this value dynamically when clock hits 1AM?

Or is there a way I can write some script/setting in IIS which stops this Service at 1 AM, changes config and restarts it? If yes how?

Comment: check hangfire for scheduling the task.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It looks like a good alternative. But doesnt fit my needs since we dont have the persistent storage thats required for Hangfire.

Comment: if you don't want to use hangfire then you can also think about using backgroundservice to poll.